# Reading input in c++ and assign to different variables

Tags: c++, cin

I am a c++ beginner. I am trying to grab some inputs from console. myconsole commmands are in "action parameter" formation

- Request a
- Create b 1
- Destroy c

Base on the input "Request" "Create" and "Destroy" then my program will decide which function to process. i know that i can use cin >> variable to do this. i made some research and come out the follow

```
    string action;
    while(true){
         cin >> action;
         cout << action << endl;
    }
```

Now the problem is i can only assign input to one variable "action", how can i assign input to another variable "parameter" and note the parameters maybe in string and integer datatype.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just add another variable, split on whitespace, whatever.  You can design it however you like.

Comment: Hi, i tried again on my visual studio and succeed, thanks all, can i delete this post?

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
string str;
int a;
double b;
char c;
cin >> str >> a >> b >> c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to read entire lines, and split those later. String streams are useful for that purpose:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string token;

    while (iss >> token)
    {
       std::cout << "Word: " << token << "\n";
       // ... process tokens; e.g. store in a container
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should point out that `std::cin` stops at the whitespaces.

Comment: @user1275129 if this is the solution, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: @user1275129: I'm very sorry, I completely screwed up the original answer. The point was to use `getline` to read an entire line. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a full text mode user interface, have a look at the CLI toolkit:
http://alexis.royer.free.fr/CLI/.
This toolkit makes it easy to define command line syntaxes (with sequences keywords and parameters, but also menus and other stuff) and plug them with the final routines that should be executed at end. The parsing is done by the library provided with the toolkit.